# Unknown error (0x80092012) - Trying to configure vagrant with Git Bash

Tags: vagrant, git-bash

While try to execute vagrant up command through Git Bash, I got this error;

schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.

Can anyone help.

EDIT: Finally, was able to sort it out. When I disabled my antivirus and run 'vagrant up' command it executed without any issue.

Comment: I have the same error. I use kaspersky.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem has to do with the firewall.

In my case, it is Avast. I'm using Windows 11. No 3rd party firewall installed. The permissions are delegated to the Avast firewall instead of the native one.

What you need to do is essentially allow traffic to the addresses/domains/ip that Vagrant communicates to initiate the downloads (picture below)

[image]
We add both `vagrantcloud.com as well as cloud-images.ubuntu.com` (this last one may change because it seems that vagrant redirects depending on the box you're downloading)

You will have to figure out how to do this from your firewall if you're using any other 3rd party one.

Now you don't have to temporarily deactivated your Antivirus/Firewall.